# Do all the Doctors have catchphrases?

Tags: doctor-who

I've not watched all the doctors (mostly just the last three) however of those I have each incarnation seems to have a phrase (or several) which they use very frequently.  These are:

- 9 - Fantastic
- 10 - Allons Y
- 11 - Geronimo

Is this just a pattern of the modern series or does it go back through most of the doctors?

Comment: #4 (Tom Baker): "Would you like a jelly baby?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### List by Doctor Number:

1. (William Hartnell): Hmmn. Hmmn. Hmmn.
2. (Patrick Troughton): When I say run.
3. (Jon Pertwee): Nothing comes to mind except Whomobile
4. (Tom Baker): Care for a Jelly baby
5. (Peter Davison): Nothing again except for Cricket & Celery
6. (Colin Baker): Got nothing
7. (Sylvester McCoy): Nothing again
8. (Paul McGann): Who am I?
9. (Christopher Eccleston): Fantastic
10. (David Tennant):
        - I'm sorry, I'm so sorry
        - Allons-y!
11. (Matt Smith):
        - `x` is/are cool
        - Geronimo
12. (Peter Capaldi):
        -  Shut up. Shutity shut up.

For better explained answer read [Does every Doctor have a catchphrase? If so what are they?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12685/does-every-doctor-have-a-catchphrase-if-so-what-are-they) or click [here](http://www.bbcamerica.com/anglophenia/2012/04/ten-of-the-doctors-most-memorable-catchphrases/).

Comment: I think it's one of those where many do but there's no hard and fast rule.  Thanks for the examples and link!

Comment: Pertwee: Reverse the Polarity of the Neutron Flow

Comment: God knows how you missed "Reverse the polarity".

Comment: @Thunderforge updated

Comment: Brave heart, Ankit... 5th Doctor! ^^

Comment: Can we add "What?!" for #10?